# What do <!--view--> and <!--anchor--> in AureliaJS tests mean?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, aurelia

I am doing a test over my custom component. Inside it, I make a `require` to a child. When testing with Karma and Jasmine, the view content of my child component is empty and appears `<!--anchor-->` tag instead.

I realised that for other other components appears `<!--view-->` and the content is rendered in test component.

Why is behaviour?

I would like to check the content of this child view.

Answer (score 0):

The  tag is a placeholder for Aurelia. Aurelia knows all about it and has stuff it wants to do there. However,  if there is just an anchor tag it means that currently that section is empty, so there is just the placeholder.

If there is just an anchor tag in your view, it is possible that your view is empty or not found.